# How can I see what went wrong inside a Github CI run

Tags: github-actions

I am new to Github CI and trying to setup Mysql with a specific username and password to test my Django project as per the below .github/workflow file but when systemctl starts mysql an error occurs:

```
Run sudo systemctl start mysql.service
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

is visible in the github actions log. The question is: how can I know what went wrong? Is there a way of viewing the output of journalctl -xe for example... Other ideas welcome.

This is my workflow file:

```
name: Django CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 4
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.6, 3.7, 3.8]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Set up MySQL 5.7
      uses: mirromutth/mysql-action@master
      with:
        mysql version: 5.7
        mysql database: apis
        mysql root password: mypassword
        mysql user: myuser
        mysql password: myotherpassword
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Run Tests
      run: |
        sudo systemctl start mysql.service
        python manage.py test
```

Comment: I tried mysql 8.0 as well, same problem

Comment: You're running the command `sudo systemctl start mysql.service` on the host whereas the action "sets up a MySQL database in Docker" (as per https://github.com/mirromutth/mysql-action)